# Simple way to replace nth element in a vector in clojure?

Tags: vector, clojure

E.g., I have a vector `[1, 2, 3]`, and I want to update the second element so that the vector becomes `[1, 5, 3]`.  In other languages, I would just do something like `array[1] = 5`, but I'm not aware of anything that would allow me to do this easily in Clojure.

Thoughts on how to accomplish this, or on whether I should be using a different data structure?

Answer (score 102, accepted):

`assoc` works fine for that. It takes the index where to put the new value and return the newly created vector:

```
Clojure> (assoc [1 2 3] 1 5)
[1 5 3]
```

Comment: Arrays are _associative_ structures, it just happens that they associate a linearly ordered index rather than a arbitrary, and usually unordered, key.

Comment: And if you need the new value as a function of the old one, use `update-in`. For example, to increment the element at index 1, you'd write `(update-in [1 2 3] [1] inc)`.

Answer (score -10):

Yve's answer doesn't show how to update the original vector.

This does, but as a Clojure noob, I'm not sure it's the best way:

```
main=> (def ar [1 2 3])
#'main/ar
main=> ar
[1 2 3]
main=> (def ar (assoc ar 1 5))
#'main/ar
main=> ar
[1 5 3]
```

Comment: That is not the Clojure way.  If you are working with an object with an identity you should use either a ref or an atom an not a var.  Updating a var in the way you indicate should typically be done only in the case of a repl.

Comment: tbc: `(def ar (atom [1 2 3]))`, `(swap! ar assoc 1 5)`